# How do i store the value and index of a python list in a variable

Tags: python-3.x, flask

```
banks = ["bank1", "bank2", "bank3", "bank4", "bank5", "bank6", "bank7", "bank8", "bank9", "bank10"]

for i, item in enumerate(banks[:5], start=1):
        print(i, item)
```

The output is

```
1 bank1
2 bank2
3 bank3
4 bank4
5 bank5
```

How can I save the result of this output in a variable?

Comment: Do you want to just store it as a string? if so you can do `banks_output = "\n".join(f"{i} {item}" for i, item in enumerate(banks[:5], start=1))`

Comment: Yes please i want it to be returned as a string

Comment: Thank you very much Chris it worked fine 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the whole thing in another list/ numpy array. It would be basically doubling your memory but you could do something like this:

```
result = []
for i, item in enumerate(banks[:5], start=1):
    result.append([i, item])
```